# Determine if two norms are equivalent.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, equivalent-metrics

In the space of functions $\mathcal{C}^1([0, 1])$ we define two norms:
$$N_1 = \bigg( \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2dx \bigg)^{1/2} + \bigg( \int_0^1 |f'(x)|^2dx \bigg)^{1/2} \\ N_2 = |f(0)| + \bigg( \int_0^1 |f'(x)|^2dx \bigg)^{1/2}$$
Determine if the two norms are equivalent.

This is part of an assignment. The answer is "yes", but I don't see it: the main reason being that while the second half of the norms are the same, I believe I can vary the first half arbitrarily with an appropriate choice of functions - thus there should be no way for me to determine appropriate constants such that:
$$ C_1 N_1 \le N_2 \le C_2 N_1 $$
I've tried with a family of functions $f(x)=e^{ax}, a\in \Bbb{R}$. The two norms yield:
$$||f||_1 = \sqrt{\frac{e^{2a}-1}{2a}} + \sqrt{\frac{a(e^{2a}-1)}{2}} \\
||f||_2 = 1 + \sqrt{\frac{a(e^{2a}-1)}{2}}$$
It looks like I can make the first term arbitrarily big or small with the choice of $a$, thus invalidating any constant. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should look at the _ratio_, not at "the first term" or whatever else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I came up with my own answer to the question, which is hopefully correct. Recall that:
$$
f(x)-f(0) = \int_0^xf'(t)dt
$$
So we start by proving:
$$|f(0)| = \bigg|f(x) + \int_x^0 f'(t)dt\bigg| \le |f(x)|+\bigg|\int_0^x f'(t)dt\bigg| \le |f(x)|+\int_0^x |f'(t)|dt$$
We may extend the rightmost integral all the way up to 1 and since the integrand is a positive function, the integral is nondecreasing in x.
$$|f(0)| \le |f(x)|+\int_0^1 |f'(t)|dt$$
Now integrating the expression and using monotonicity, leaving the real numbers the same since we're integrating on an interval of unitary measure:
$$|f(0)| \le \int_0^1|f(x)|dx +\int_0^1 |f'(x)|dx$$
In general, by Hölder's inequality:
$$||f||_{L^1([0, 1])} \le ||f||_{L^2([0, 1])}\\
\implies \int_0^1|f(x)|dx+\int_0^1 |f'(x)|dx \le \Big(\int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx\Big)^{1/2} +\Big(\int_0^1 |f'(x)|^2dx\Big)^{1/2} $$
And this implies finally that:
$$ |f(0)| \le \Big(\int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx\Big)^{1/2} +\Big(\int_0^1 |f'(x)|^2dx\Big)^{1/2}\\
\implies N_2 \le 2N_1 $$

For the other direction:
$$ (a+b)^2 \le 2a^2 + 2b^2 \\
\implies |f(x)|^2 \le \bigg|2(f(0))^2 + 2\Big(\int_0^x f'(t)dt\Big)^2\bigg| \le 2\Big(|f(0)|^2 + \bigg|\int_0^x f'(t)dt\bigg|^2) \le 2\Big(|f(0)|^2 + \big(\int_0^x |f'(t)|dt\big)^2\Big)
$$
So we're using the same tricks as before (most of the absolute values are redundant, but I'll keep them). Then we use an inequality for square roots that holds for positive $a, b$:
$$ (a+b)^{1/2} \le a^{1/2} + b^{1/2} $$
So we will integrate the above over the interval after extending the integral over to 1, then apply the square root inequality:
$$\int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx \le 2\Big(|f(0)|^2 + \big(\int_0^1 |f'(t)|dt\big)^2\Big) \\
\implies \Big(\int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx\Big)^{1/2} \le \sqrt{2}|f(0)| + \sqrt{2}\int_0^1 |f'(x)|dx \le \sqrt{2}|f(0)| + \sqrt{2}\Big(\int_0^1 |f'(x)|^2dx\Big)^{1/2}$$
So we determine that:
$$N_1 \le (\sqrt{2} + 1)N_2$$

Answer (score 1):

In your example with $f(x)=e^{ax}, a\in \Bbb{R}$, the terms are equivalent as $a\to 0$ and as $a\to \infty$ hence this does not give a counter-example.

Here are some hints to prove the equivalence of the norms.

1. Notice that 
   $$f(x)^2\leqslant 2(f(x)-f(0))^2+f(0)^2 $$
   and by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f(x)-f(0) =\int_0^xf'(t)dt$
   hence $$f(x)^2\leqslant 2\left(\int_0^x\left\lvert f'(t)\right\rvert dt\right)^2+f(0)^2\leqslant 2\left(\int_0^1\left\lvert f'(t)\right\rvert dt\right)^2+f(0)^2.$$

   Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we get 
   $$f(x)^2\leqslant   2 \int_0^1\left\lvert f'(t)\right\rvert ^2dt +f(0)^2 .$$
2. For the opposite direction, an other use of the fundamental theorem of calculus shows that  for all $x\in[0,1]$, 
   $$ f(x)^2=2\int_0^x f'(t)f(t)dt+f(0)^2.$$
   Therefore, 
   $$
   f(0)^2\leqslant f(x)^2+2\int_0^x \left\lvert f'(t)f(t)\right\rvert dt\leqslant f(x)^2+2\int_0^1 \left\lvert f'(t)f(t)\right\rvert dt
   $$
   Integrate this equality with respect to $x$ on $[0,1]$ and use the fact that $2\left\lvert f'(t)f(t)\right\rvert\leqslant f'(t)^2+f(t)^2 $ to conclude.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake with one of your hints and I'm stuck again. Can you post the whole solution?

Comment: Which part exactly makes you stuck?

Comment: The worst is integeating the equalities that already have an integral in them.

Comment: It turns out that we can continue the bound before integrating, avoiding in this way the double integral.

Comment: So 2. proves that $f^2(0)\le f^2(x)$, thus transferring to the integrals. And that proves $N_2 \le N_1$. I'm still not sure about 1.

Comment: Or maybe it does not. I swear, three years of undergrad analysis and this is the first time I'm truly stuck on something.